# Replication - Is it possible to publish to different servers?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-replication, database-backups

I use mssqlserver08 with ssms, and want to publish tables to two different servers.

One server is used to run my application, the other is used to backup data, and the tables' schema are the same.

1.Is it possible to publish same tables to different servers?

2.Is there any better way to backup data Immediately?

Comment: yes .

using Replication you can publish to different servers..

Comment: Thanks, I did my test and it worked.